# Did UNetbootin actually Install Ubuntu in Windows 7?

Tags: unetbootin

I was using UNetbootin on my laptop to retreive Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and create a live CD. I wanted to use Ubuntu to remove a virus that I have in Windows XP on my home PC. Now when I boot my laptop, I am asked to select either Windows 7 or UNetbootin. If I select UNetbootin, it appears that Ubuntu is installed on my PC because I don't have the CD/DVD loaded but Ubuntu runs. In ADD/REMOVE programs, only UNetbootin appears, no Ubuntu. Can someone offer some advice? I thought I was saving the Ubuntu iso to my laptop hard drive so I could later create the Ubuntu live CD to use in my home PC.

Comment: Did you use unetbootin to create a bootable usb-key installer, is the usb key still plugged in?

Comment: Additional information: There is no Ubuntu partition when I look at Disk Management, only System Reserve (100 MB) and C: drive. When I look in Windows Explorer, under Computer it indicates "Install Ubuntu (C:)" with a red circle logo (Ubuntu?) preceeding it.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem could be, while creating the ubuntu live cd, you have possibly specified some drive (C: or D: or E: something like that, which is a partition of your present hard drive). You might have failed to locate the drive letter of your removable media.

This has caused the installation of ubuntu into that partition instead of the usb-flash-drive. The drive now behaves as if it were a usb drive that is attached to the computer, and so, you are getting an option to boot from the so called virtual drive.

Please check this.

Comment: My intent was to install the iso on my laptop and later burn it to a CD to use to remove a virus on my desktop PC running Winsdows XP. When I ran UNetbootin I did not have a usb flash drive or a blank CD/DVD loaded in my laptop.

Comment: I see the following installed folders on my laptop C: drive: ".disk", boot, casper, dists, install, isolinux, pic, pool, preseed, and unetbtin and the following files: ubnldr, ubnldr.exe, ubnldr.mbr, unetbtin.exe, and wubi.exe. All of these were created the same date that I ran UNetbottin.

Comment: Can it be that Ubuntu runs within UNetbootin and not actually be installed on my C:drive? If I use ADD/REMOVE in Windows to remove UNetbootin, will the added folders/files be deleted too? At work now, guess I'll try it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the wubi installer then, it will install the complete operating system on any partition you like, just make sure there is enough space available on the partition. Also use ubuntu 12.10 or less version, since there is wubi is not supported for 13.04 distro.

for wubi installation instructions, you might need to check this

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

download it, and mount the ubuntu iso using daemon tools or some other such software, and then run the downloaded wubi.exe. After installation completes, reboot and wait for the ubuntu installation to complete. This will install complete operating system. Once your work is over, you can safely uninstall the whole operating system by uninstalling the wubi from Control Panel -> Add-Remove Programs. Hope this does.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't get a chance to try it last night, but I will tonight.